# Android custom progressbar dialog : Freeze screen

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I had created custom Dotted Progressbar by extending view class, When this progressbar shows i have to freeze the below UI, How can i do this.?

Comment: What do you mean, when you tell freeze? You need to stop UI thread or just prevent possibility to invoke events at  UI bellow?

Comment: You can show progress in popup and make popup not removable by touch or back button. It will do the job.

Comment: @Preetygeek thats what i want to suggest, he should use an dialog.

Comment: Beside freezing ui is terrible idea. You can add flag in your activity and check for touches and key press. If state is progress display some info with popup.

Answer (score 0):

**Write your Progress Code in AysncTask and Call it using `get()` to make rest of UI Freeze**

```
new YourAsyncTask().get();
```

**This will make your UI freeze Until PostExecute of AysncTask completes Execution ,after that UI will Function as intended**